# Is it possible to access an index on a casted expression?

Tags: php, arrays, syntax

I am trying to deal with some input that may or may not be an array, with the intent of obtaining the first item if the input is an array, and the item itself otherwise.

Here is how I was planning to go about it:

```
$payload = ((array)json_decode($mapOrArray))[0];
```

This did not sit well with the interpreter, however. Instead, I am currently using this:

```
$payload = array_values((array)json_decode($mapOrArray))[0];
```

Only once I've wrapped the casted array in a useless method call can I use this approach.

Is accessing an index of the result of a cast impossible with a single statement? If so, what is a better way to deal with this task, preferably without introducing an extraneous variable?

Comment: [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23455039/383793), but why?

Comment: @ChrisWesseling Your answer solves the problem, but it is not a "yes". You haven't demonstrated that it is possible to access an index on a casted expression.

Comment: Yup, just does the intended case, not the general one from the title. But still, why? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list($payload) = (array) json_decode($mapOrArray);
```